# AdaptiveFact() for having a dynamic value as URI

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am using an adaptive card (1.0) & am trying to give a hyperlink for the user to click so that he/she can navigate to a particular ServiceNow ticket.
I am not able to figure out how the dynamic sys_id can be passed to the hyperlink as the URI/URN.
The hyperlink for the ticket changes for each ticket so it has to be dynamic. But I am not seeing an option to make the URI/URN dynamic.

I have tried escaping & separating the numbers from texts.

```
new AdaptiveFact()
{
    Title="More Information",
    Value ="[Click here to open the ticket in SNOW](https://URL.service-now.com/)"                                                    

}
```

I should be able to take sys_id as a parameter(URI/URN) to navigate to the exact incident in SNOW.

The complete Card generator code is as below

```
        AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard("1.0");
        card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveContainer()
        {
            Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                    {
                        new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                        {
                             Text= $"Ticket Status for {JSONArray.1stElementname.ToUpper()} is as follows.",
                              Weight= AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                              Size=  AdaptiveTextSize.Large

                        },
                        new AdaptiveColumnSet()
                        {
                            Columns = new List<AdaptiveColumn>()
                            {
                                new AdaptiveColumn()
                                {
                                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                    {
                                        new AdaptiveFactSet()
                                        {
                                            Facts  = new List<AdaptiveFact>()
                                            {

                                                 new AdaptiveFact()
                                                {
                                                    Title="Short Description",
                                                    Value=JSONArray.2ndElementname

                                                },
                                                 new AdaptiveFact()
                                                {
                                                    Title="More Information",
                                                    Value ="[Click here to open the ticket in SNOW](https://service-now.com/JSONArray.3rdDElementname)"

                                                }





                                            },
                                            Separator = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
        });

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
            Content = card
        };

        return attachment;
```

Comment: Can you add how you are creating your adaptive card? Are you just trying to dynamically change the URL in the adaptive card?

Comment: @tdurnford - I have edited the question with the information you requested. Yes- That is correct. I am trying to dynamically change the URL.

Comment: @tdurnford - Value ="[Click here to open the ticket in SNOW](https://service-now.com/JSONArray.3rdDElementname)"  works whereas Value ="[Click here to open the ticket in SNOW]("https://service-now.com/JSONArray.3rdDElementname/"+someDynamicText)" doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried `Value = $"[Click here to open the ticket in SNOW](https://service-now.com/{JSONArray.3rdDElementname})"`. Here is the documentation on [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked as expected.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to insert the data from the JSON object into your URL. Right now "JSONArray.3rdDElementname" is just rendering as part of the URL instead of pulling the value from the object. Try using string interpolation.

```
Value = $"[Click here to open the ticket in SNOW](https://service-now.com/{JSONArray.3rdDElementname})"
```

Here is more [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) on how to interpolation data into a string.

Glad this helped.